# Incorrect results from C++ math library's trigonometry functions

Tags: c++, trigonometry, cmath

I'm currently working on a personal project that I've been doing for nearly a year now. I am trying to port it over to a Windows environment, which has succeeded. Because I am trying to get a Windows version out to people soon, I decided to continue to develop in Windows while I try to add new features and get bugs that have existed for months out. While recently attempting to add functionality which relied heavily on trigonometry, I found that all 3 trigonometric functions, oddly enough, returned the same value (1072693887) regardless of the parameter I passed. As you can imagine, this is leading to some rather strange bugs in the system.

I have math.h included, and to my knowledge no other files that would contain this function. (Perhaps there's a debugger command to find where a symbol is defined? I couldn't find any such thing, but perhaps I missed something.) I've tried asking elsewhere and searching around on Google, but to no avail...

Has anyone else heard of this problem before, or know how to fix it?

Comment: How about showing code?

Comment: What does the number you are passing mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All I know is that GDB is telling me the result of it is 1072693887, that it's occurring with all 3 of my trig functions (and that the arc versions of all three of them just return -1072693887) regardless of what parameter I pass.

Might be a GDB issue. What happens if you just manually print the values to the console?

Comment: I wish I could answer that... For some reason, even though Code::Blocks has it set up to run as a "Console Application", none of my calls to std::cout or printf are actually showing up...

Comment: Then you have far more serious problems that rounding issues. What happens if you insert a `std::cin.peek();` line at the very end of `main`?

Comment: Well, the console is opening, and I do get a "Press any key to continue" at the end of execution... But whether I run my code from within Code::Blocks or I just open up cmd.exe and run my program, either way I don't get any output, despite having calls to std::cout peppered in my code... And that's only happening on Windows...

Comment: Alright, well, I just tested it on Linux as well... Apparently it is just a problem with my debugger, because I did manage to get my std::cout calls to execute there, and it did in fact tell me the correct numbers... *sigh* Thanks for all the help, anyway...

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT : This answer is not relevant. See comments.**

---

This is probably due to numerical instability.

When you pass such a large value into `sin()`, `cos()`, or any of the periodic trig functions, you have to remember that there's an implicit modulo by `2*pi`.

If you are using `float`, then the uncertainty of `1072693887`, is way more than `2*pi`. Therefore, whatever result you get is garbage.

We'll need to see some code to be able to see exactly what's going on though.

**EDIT : Here's an illustration:**

```
sin(1072693886) =  0.6783204666
sin(1072693887) = -0.2517863119
sin(1072693888) = -0.9504019164
```

But if the datatype is `float`, then the uncertainty of `1072693887` is `+/- ~64`...

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more clear... If I put in a value, say PI/3 (for which the value should be the square root of 3, or approximately 0.866), I get 1072693886 as a return value from the trig function.

Comment: Then that sounds like a clear bug in your code. Post your code so we can take a look at it. Otherwise, we won't be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

1072693887 is 3FF207FF in hexadecimal, which represents 1.8908690 in IEEE single precision floating point. Are you sure your problem isn't just a representation one, ie you are casting or view the result as a integer?

Comment: All I know is that GDB is telling me the result of it is 1072693887, that it's occurring with all 3 of my trig functions (and that the arc versions of all three of them just return -1072693887) regardless of what parameter I pass. Even if what you say is true, it still appears to be a clear-cut error.

Comment: So post a repro case showing what you are doing, otherwise all you will get is wild guesses. The gnu math library is extremely well tested and used in literally millions of applications where results are put under the highest scrutiny, the likelihood you have found a bug is vanishingly small

Answer (score 0):

Math library is fine.

You realize that the functions expect radians as input right?

E.g. :

```
double param = 90.0;
double rads = param * M_PI/180;
std::cout << std::fixed << "Angle : " << param << " sin : " << sin (rads) << " cos " << cos(rads);
```

Output :

```
Angle : 90.000000 sin : 1.000000 cos 0.000000-0.304811
```

Comment: This is true, and is the cause of many (most?) *"math.h doesn't work"* complaints, but the "symptom" is random seeming results, not one consistent value.

Comment: First of all, I am inputting radians. Secondly, even if I were mistakenly inputting degrees, the range of sin and cos are 1 (even if tan has an infinite range). sin of any number and cos of any number should still not return 1072683887.

Comment: @drummerp Post a minimal sample of code which reproduces this. Otherwise we can just guess.

Comment: Hm... This is interesting. I tried creating a new project to test it with a single file looking like this:

`#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "The sin of 30 degrees is: " << sin(30 * (M_PI / 180)) << endl;
    return 0;
}`

It did, in fact, return 0.5.

Comment: @drummerp So the bug lies somewhere else :)

Comment: I can't imagine where though... I never knowingly included anything that has other functions by that name... And even if I did, wouldn't my compiler be complaining about an ambiguous usage of "sin"? Since I know I'm including math.h, wouldn't the fact that it compiles and runs indicate that it has to be using the trig functions in math.h?

Comment: @drummerp, Try including math.h inside namespace, that way you can isolate it and test it.

Comment: @drummerp Try replacing your sin in your code with ::sin(...).

Comment: @drummerp: If you are using C++ then include `<cmath>` instead of `<math.h>`.

Comment: I changed it to <cmath>. It now says that the answer is 1071645311. I'll try the ::sin solution... EDIT: Using the global namespace operator didn't help either...